Is there a way to use dynamically invoke a method based on a bounded generic parameter's type?
I've set the following up as an example.
I have an interface Foo with various implementations that doThing. I understand that polymorphism allows different implementations of Foo to be stored in a collection of Foo, where each can call their respective doThing implementation. Can we do something similar based on the bounded generic parameter's type, like I try with the Consumer<> printer? It would be very convenient to be able to do this.
import java.util.function.Consumer

public class Tester {

  interface Foo {

    String doThing();

    static String doThing(Class<? extends Foo> clazz) {
      return "Class: "+clazz.getSimpleName();
    }

    static String doThing(Enum<? extends Foo> e) {
      return "Enum: "+e.name();
    }

    static <T extends Foo> String doThing(T e) {
      return e.doThing();
    }
  }

  record Bar() implements Foo {

    @Override
    String doThing() {
      return "doing bar";
    }
  }

  enum EnumBar implements Foo {

    ENUMFOO;

    @Override
    String doThing() {
      return "doing "+this.name();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(Foo.doThing(Bar.class)); // Output: "Class: Bar"
    System.out.println(Foo.doThing(new Bar())); // Output: "doing bar"
    System.out.println(Foo.doThing(EnumBar.ENUMFOO)); // Output: "Enum: ENUMFOO"

    Consumer<? extends Foo> printer = f -> System.out.println(Foo.doThing(f));
    
    // Ideal behaviour
    // printer.accept(Bar.class); // Output: "Class: Bar"
    // printer.accept(new Bar()); // Output: "doing bar"
    // printer.accept(EnumBar.ENUMFOO); // Output: "Enum: ENUMFOO"
  }
}

I tried to achieve a similar behaviour where the various static String doThing logic for each type (Class object, object, enum) is all done in one doThing(Object object) but the compiler wouldn't let me safely cast into the various types. Am I forced into using reflection? Or perhaps something with sealed class and the permitted subclasses, but then how does one automatically wrap it with the correct subclass?

No, you can't do this.  A Consumer only knows how to take one type.  If you want to handle multiple types, you will need to either check which class it is (with reflection or instanceof), or create instances of a Foo-like interface (without lambdas, since it has multiple methods).
